# How can I find the code I need based on multiple lookup values in my table, based on data in a reference table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to find the code for the best match in a table using 4 lookup values.

In the image below the left table A to E is a static table and is the reference table

The right table normally on a separate sheet has multiple lines of varying data, where I need to find the correct **code** based matching the Name, Age and Age Calc from, using the information in the reference table.

I have tried VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH, but I'm struggling with the multiple lookup values.

The answers I need in J are: 5678, 7654, 4679, 7654, 1234.
What would be my best method of achieving my code results?

[image: LOOKUP]

Comment: There's quite a difference between "best" and "exact" match.  If you mean "best" match, you'd need to define the rules used to match by.

Comment: Well I don't think VLOOKUP uses multiple values so I gave up with that. I then tried index/match as a single value: =INDEX(E2:E6,MATCH(G2,A2:A6,0)), but I don't know how to make it work across all the values to get the best match. I don't even know if Index/Match is my best option. It may even need to be some VBA code.

Comment: It's needs to be an exact match, but I used best because of the age range, i.e. it needs to sit within the correct age range, which is where I'm really struggling to workout how I use Index/match to see if the single age is between the reference ages

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,G2,B:B,"<="&H2,C:C,">="&H2,D:D,I2)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that worked a treat. Just as I thought I was on the wrong track. Thank you for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, SUMIFS hasn't quite worked out as the code values include Letters as well as numbers and in my example I only gave numbers, which is why it worked. So where the code is only numbers it works fine, but not on the codes with Letters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be only one match, then do something like:

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$6,$A$2:$A$6,G2,$B$2:$B$6,"<="&H2,$C$2:$C$6,">="&H2,$D$2:$D$6,I2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula that worked for me.

=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E$2:E$6)/(A$2:A$6=G2)/(B$2:B$6<=H2)/(C$2:C$6>=H2)/(D$2:D$6=I2),1))